# Cannot display data in view from Many to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Ok, so i'm having a bit of trouble getting my Edit view to display a field that allows me to select multiple qualifications for employees.

A bit of background - I work for a company that has asked me to create and employee database/web app that they can use to find people with the relevant skills for certain job requirements.

I am pretty new to C#, MVC, Entity framework, SQL (to be fair, just software development in general) however I do have a strong IT background and I am able to pick things up relatively quickly.

I decided to use an Entity Framework Code First for my approach and it's not been too rough going... So far.

As stated above, I am having trouble displaying a field in my edit view that allows me to select multiple qualifications from a many to many relationship in my database.  See screenshot.
[image: Edit View Capture]

My model is as follows

```
    namespace reBase.Models
{
    [Table("contactsTbl")]
    public class contactsClass
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([A-Za-z])+$", ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Vaild Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Surname")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([A-Za-z])+$", ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Vaild Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
        [RegularExpression(@"([0-9])")]
        public string MobNo { get; set; }
        public string LandLine { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$",
        ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a vaild Email Address")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"£[0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Valid Rate (£ required)")]
        public string HourlyRate { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }

        public Nullable<int> empStatusID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> regionID { get; set; }
        public bool isOnSite { get; set; }

        public virtual empStatusClass empStatusClass { get; set; }
        public virtual regionsClass regionsClass { get; set; }

        public List<tradesClass> tradesClass { get; set; }
        public List<ticketsClass> ticketsClass { get; set; }

    }

    [Table("empStatusTbl")]
    public partial class empStatusClass
    {
        public empStatusClass()

        {
            this.contactsClass = new HashSet<contactsClass>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int empStatusID { get; set; }
        public string employmentStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<contactsClass> contactsClass { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("regionTbl")]
    public partial class regionsClass
    {
        public regionsClass()

        {
            this.contactsClass = new HashSet<contactsClass>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int regionID { get; set; }
        public string regionName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<contactsClass> contactsClass { get; set; }
    }


    [Table("tradesTbl")]
    public class tradesClass
    {

        [Key]
        public int tradeID { get; set; }
        public string tradeName { get; set; }

        public List<contactsClass> contactsClass { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("ticketsTbl")]
    public class ticketsClass
    {

        [Key]
        public int ticketID { get; set; }
        public string ticketName { get; set; }

        public List<contactsClass> contactsClass { get; set; }
    }

    //
    //DbContext for dataModel

    public partial class dataEntityModel : DbContext
    {
        public dataEntityModel()
            : base("name=dataEntityModel")
        {

        }

        public virtual DbSet<contactsClass> contactClasses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<empStatusClass> empStatClasses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<regionsClass> regionClasses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tradesClass> tradeClasses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ticketsClass> ticketClasses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<contactsClass>().HasMany(x => x.ticketsClass).WithMany(x => x.contactsClass);
            modelBuilder.Entity<contactsClass>().HasMany(x => x.tradesClass).WithMany(x => x.contactsClass);
        }


    }
}
```

This is the Controller

```
    namespace reBase.Controllers
{
    public class contactsClassesController : Controller
    {
        private dataEntityModel db = new dataEntityModel();

        // GET: contactsClasses
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var contactClasses = db.contactClasses.Include(c => c.empStatusClass).Include(c => c.regionsClass);
            return View(contactClasses.ToList());
        }

        // GET: contactsClasses/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses.Find(id);
            if (contactsClass == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contactsClass);
        }

        // GET: contactsClasses/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.empStatusID = new SelectList(db.empStatClasses, "empStatusID", "employmentStatus");
            ViewBag.regionID = new SelectList(db.regionClasses, "regionID", "regionName");
            ViewBag.ticketsClass = new SelectList(db.ticketClasses, "ticketID", "ticketName");
            ViewBag.tradesClass = new SelectList(db.tradeClasses, "tradeID", "tradeName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: contactsClasses/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,FirstName,LastName,MobNo,LandLine,EmailAddress,HourlyRate,empStatusID,regionID,isOnSite")] contactsClass contactsClass)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.contactClasses.Add(contactsClass);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.empStatusID = new SelectList(db.empStatClasses, "empStatusID", "employmentStatus", contactsClass.empStatusID);
            ViewBag.regionID = new SelectList(db.regionClasses, "regionID", "regionName", contactsClass.regionID);
            ViewBag.ticketsClass = new SelectList(db.ticketClasses, "ticketID", "ticketName", contactsClass.ticketsClass);
            ViewBag.tradesClass = new SelectList(db.tradeClasses, "tradeID", "tradeName", contactsClass.tradesClass);
            return View(contactsClass);
        }

        // GET: contactsClasses/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses.Find(id);
            if (contactsClass == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.empStatusID = new SelectList(db.empStatClasses, "empStatusID", "employmentStatus", contactsClass.empStatusID);
            ViewBag.regionID = new SelectList(db.regionClasses, "regionID", "regionName", contactsClass.regionID);
            ViewBag.ticketsClass = new SelectList(db.ticketClasses, "ticketID", "ticketName", contactsClass.ticketsClass);
            ViewBag.tradesClass = new SelectList(db.tradeClasses, "tradeID", "tradeName", contactsClass.tradesClass);
            return View(contactsClass);
        }

        // POST: contactsClasses/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,FirstName,LastName,MobNo,LandLine,EmailAddress,HourlyRate,empStatusID,regionID,isOnSite")] contactsClass contactsClass)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(contactsClass).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.empStatusID = new SelectList(db.empStatClasses, "empStatusID", "employmentStatus", contactsClass.empStatusID);
            ViewBag.regionID = new SelectList(db.regionClasses, "regionID", "regionName", contactsClass.regionID);
            ViewBag.ticketsClass = new SelectList(db.ticketClasses, "ticketID", "ticketName", contactsClass.ticketsClass);
            ViewBag.tradesClass = new SelectList(db.tradeClasses, "tradeID", "tradeName", contactsClass.tradesClass);
            return View(contactsClass);
        }

        // GET: contactsClasses/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses.Find(id);
            if (contactsClass == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contactsClass);
        }

        // POST: contactsClasses/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses.Find(id);
            db.contactClasses.Remove(contactsClass);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I have only been learning for a couple of months, so I apologize if this is something glaringly obvious, but I have tried to refrain from asking the question on here and I have tried a myriad of things to get this to work.

Any help you can provide will be massively appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

--------EDIT---------
[image]

Comment: You need a dropdown for `ticketclass`?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking for help getting the `ticketsclass` field working?

Comment: Yes that's correct, sorry, I wasn't very specific with that. I was getting ready to leave work when I typed this out. There is a table (class) called 'ticketsClass' which contains a list of qualifications that can (should) be assigned to a contact in the 'contactsClass' table. There is an intermediate table that sits between these two classes to facilitate the Many to Many relationship, called 'ticketsClass_contactsClasscontactsClass' (I realize this naming convention is ridiculous, and is something I will rectify later on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to get it working.

See below code and compare against my original question.

A lot of additional stuff was required in the controller for the contactsClass.

contactsClass Controller

```
    namespace reBase.Controllers
{
    public class contactsClassesController : Controller
    {
        private dataEntityModel db = new dataEntityModel();

        // GET: contactsClasses
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var contactClasses = db.contactClasses.Include(c => c.empStatusClass).Include(c => c.regionsClass);
            return View(contactClasses.ToList());
        }

        // GET: contactsClasses/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses.Find(id);
            if (contactsClass == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contactsClass);
        }

        // GET: contactsClasses/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.TeamID = new SelectList(db.ticketClasses, "ticketID", "ticketName");
            var contact = new contactsClass();
            contact.tickets = new List<ticketsClass>();
            populateAssignedTicketData(contact);
            ViewBag.empStatusID = new SelectList(db.empStatClasses, "empStatusID", "employmentStatus");
            ViewBag.regionID = new SelectList(db.regionClasses, "regionID", "regionName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: contactsClasses/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,FirstName,LastName,MobNo,LandLine,EmailAddress,HourlyRate,empStatusID,regionID,isOnSite")] contactsClass contactsClass)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.contactClasses.Add(contactsClass);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


            ViewBag.empStatusID = new SelectList(db.empStatClasses, "empStatusID", "employmentStatus", contactsClass.empStatusID);
            ViewBag.regionID = new SelectList(db.regionClasses, "regionID", "regionName", contactsClass.regionID);
            populateAssignedTicketData(contactsClass);
            return View(contactsClass);
        }

        // GET: contactsClasses/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            //contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses.Find(id);
            contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses
                          .Include(p => p.tickets)
                          .Where(i => i.ID == id)
                          .Single();

            if (contactsClass == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.empStatusID = new SelectList(db.empStatClasses, "empStatusID", "employmentStatus", contactsClass.empStatusID);
            ViewBag.regionID = new SelectList(db.regionClasses, "regionID", "regionName", contactsClass.regionID);
            populateAssignedTicketData(contactsClass);
            return View(contactsClass);
        }
        private void populateAssignedTicketData(contactsClass contactsClass)
        {
            var allTickets = db.ticketClasses;
            var contactTicket = new HashSet<int>(contactsClass.tickets.Select(b => b.ticketID));
            var viewModelAvailable = new List<contactTicketVM>();
            var viewModelSelected = new List<contactTicketVM>();
            foreach (var ticket in allTickets)
            {
                if (contactTicket.Contains(ticket.ticketID))
                {
                    viewModelSelected.Add(new contactTicketVM
                    {
                        ticketID = ticket.ticketID,
                        ticketName = ticket.ticketName,
                        //Assigned = true
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    viewModelAvailable.Add(new contactTicketVM
                    {
                        ticketID = ticket.ticketID,
                        ticketName = ticket.ticketName,
                        //Assigned = false
                    });
                }
            }

            ViewBag.selOpts = new MultiSelectList(viewModelSelected, "ticketID", "ticketName");
            ViewBag.availOpts = new MultiSelectList(viewModelAvailable, "ticketID", "ticketName");
        }

        // POST: contactsClasses/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id, [Bind(Include = "ID,FirstName,LastName,MobNo,LandLine,EmailAddress,HourlyRate,empStatusID,regionID,isOnSite")] contactsClass contactsClass, string[] selectedOptions)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(contactsClass).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var contactToUpdate = db.contactClasses
    .Include(p => p.tickets)
    .Where(i => i.ID == id)
    .Single();
            if (TryUpdateModel(contactToUpdate, "",
                   new string[] { "ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "MobNo", "LandLine", "EmailAddress", "HourlyRate", "isOnSite", "empStatusID", "regionID" }))
            {
                try
                {
                    updateContactTickets(selectedOptions, contactToUpdate);

                    db.Entry(contactToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                }
            }


            ViewBag.empStatusID = new SelectList(db.empStatClasses, "empStatusID", "employmentStatus", contactsClass.empStatusID);
            ViewBag.regionID = new SelectList(db.regionClasses, "regionID", "regionName", contactsClass.regionID);
            populateAssignedTicketData(contactToUpdate);
            return View(contactToUpdate);
        }
        private void updateContactTickets(string[] selectedOptions, contactsClass contactToUpdate)
        {
            if (selectedOptions == null)
            {
                contactToUpdate.tickets = new List<ticketsClass>();
                return;
            }

            var selectedOptionsHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedOptions);
            var contactTickets = new HashSet<int>
                (contactToUpdate.tickets.Select(b => b.ticketID));
            foreach (var ticket in db.ticketClasses)
            {
                if (selectedOptionsHS.Contains(ticket.ticketID.ToString()))
                {
                    if (!contactTickets.Contains(ticket.ticketID))
                    {
                        contactToUpdate.tickets.Add(ticket);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (contactTickets.Contains(ticket.ticketID))
                    {
                        contactToUpdate.tickets.Remove(ticket);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // GET: contactsClasses/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses.Find(id);
            if (contactsClass == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contactsClass);
        }

        // POST: contactsClasses/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses.Find(id);
            db.contactClasses.Remove(contactsClass);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Edit View

```
    @model reBase.Models.contactsClass

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Edit</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>contactsClass</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { 
    @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LandLine, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LandLine, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LandLine, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HourlyRate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HourlyRate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HourlyRate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.empStatusID, "empStatusID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("empStatusID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.empStatusID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.regionID, "regionID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("regionID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.regionID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.isOnSite, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.isOnSite)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.isOnSite, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Current Tickets</label>
                @Html.ListBox("selectedOptions", 
   (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.selOpts, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" id="btnRight" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" id="btnLeft" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Assign Tickets</label>
                @Html.ListBox("availOptions", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.availOpts, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

A View Model was also Added

```
namespace reBase.ViewModels
{
    public class contactTicketVM
    {
        public int ticketID { get; set; }
        public string ticketName { get; set; }
        public bool Assigned { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your help in this matter

Answer (score 1):

First, Model.ticketsClass is Collection 
You can't use editorfor collection
plus Model.ticketsClass will be the existing relationships only, if for display purpose you can do this, note that you currently using find which wil not include the existing relationship use select include instead and do something like this

```
@foreach(var TicketClass in Model.ticketclass)
{
   @Html.Display(TicketClass.ticketName)
   }
```

if you want the user to see all available ticket classes and edit accordingly 
I suggest you do something like this, pass all classes as list of ticketClass in viewbag and do something like this

```
@foreach(var TicketClass in (List<TicketClass>)ViewBag.ticketclasses)
{
<!-- the if condition inside the checkbox is to check if the relationship already exist --> 
   <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="TicketClass_@TicketClass.ticketID" title="@TicketClass.ticketName" @(if(Model.ticketsClass.where(f => f.ticketId == TicketClass.ticketId).FirstOrDefault() != null){"Checked"}) />

   }
```

then in your controller do something to get all submitted ticket classes and removing old one 
example

```
// first remove all existing relationships
// then get submitted classes to the form using Formcollection  
foreach (var item in formcollection.AllKeys.Where(x => x.Contains("TicketClass_")))
{
 /// add the relationship again  
  }
```

of course there are many ways of implementing the logic this is one of them

Comment: Thank you for your reply. to be honest, i understand some of what you have said but i'm not entirely sure how to implement this.

You say to use 'Select Include' instead of 'Find'

I assume you mean this line in the controller

              `contactsClass contactsClass = db.contactClasses.Find(id);
            if (contactsClass == null)`

Not entirely sure how to use 'Select' and 'Include' in this context.

Thanks

Comment: You used it in your index controller, just add first or default to that 

    `var contactClasses = db.contactClasses.Include(c => c.empStatusClass).Include(c => c.regionsClass).Include(c => c.ticketsClass_contactsClass).FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);`
then pass this model to your view

Comment: Feel free to ask me anything

Comment: Good Morning! Thanks for the reply. I have had a look at your solution this morning. Problem is, intellisense is not bringing up ticketsClass_contactsClass when I try to use it (it is now also contactsClassticketsClasses)

Comment: I apologize but yesterday between replies I was still also trying to work it out myself. my Model has changed a little, and I have re-scaffolded the controller and view. I'll reflect this in an edit in my post. Sorry to mess you about. I will save a copy of the project from this point on and keep any of my own work separate. Thank you

Comment: Hello, 
You should include the collection related which is actually virtual collection, this collection will be the list of the existing ticketclasses for this contact class 
`db.contactClasses.Include(c => c.tradesClass ).Include(c => c.ticketsClass ).FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);`
this will load first entity matching your condition and will include the trades class and tickets class that have an existing relationship with the loaded contact class 
Hope it is clear now

Comment: Hi. Yes I have tried this but I get the following

`'contactsClass' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'contactsClass' could be found`

Comment: And also `The name 'id' does not exist in the current context `

Comment: It is ID sorry my bad, i thought you would figure it out alone, it is straight forward, you are searching by property and you should know that id in your entity is ID.

Comment: Hi, yeah sorry thats just how I typed it. Intellisense brought up c.ID, which is what I used the first time around, but I still get the second error on the final part of the lambda of `The name 'id' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: I have tried changing that to reflect the column in the ticketsClass table (IE '== ticketID', but still get the same error. See above photo i have added to post

Comment: id is the id of the contact class that you are editing,
I don't know why that code is in index while i guess we were talking about edit.

Comment: well id or ID, either way I get the same error. 
So I should add this code to my edit, create and details actions as well??

Comment: your question was, Error displaying  m t m relationship 
I proposed the answer for it up, 
then I also showed how to add the relationship 
whether it is for your index create edit, it can be used everywhere,  of course for adding it you won't need that for your index, only showing is needed, and for adding part you may need it for create and edit, 
I really suggest you go through my answer again, it has everything you want, and i suggest you reading this 

[link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation)

Comment: I will have a look through the link. Thanks

Comment: Good Luck, I hope I helped.